# Why does JQuery trigger( "remove") do the same as remove() with no trigger?

Tags: jquery, triggers

Seems the following code:

```
$("#logo-events").trigger("remove");
```

Does same thing as

```
$("#logo-events").remove();
```

Is that expected behavior?
You can try it at [jquery](https://jquery.com/) website opening a console.

Comment: Why would you expect any different? Or better what would you expect and why? Trigger: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type. Remove is the actual event.

Comment: The trigger docs say _`For both plain objects and DOM objects other than window, if a triggered event name matches the name of a property on the object, jQuery will attempt to invoke the property as a method if no event handler calls event.preventDefault().`_ but remove is a method not a property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

> For both plain objects and DOM objects other than window, if a
>   triggered event name matches the name of a property on the object,
>   jQuery will [attempt to invoke the property as a method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L386) if no event
>   handler calls event.preventDefault(). If this behavior is not desired,
>   use .triggerHandler() instead

[`.remove()`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-childnode-remove) is a native function of the DOM:

> The remove() method, when invoked, must run these steps:
>   - If context object’s parent is null, terminate these steps.
>   - Remove the context object from context object’s parent.

Combine these two and you get the observed behaviour.
When you trigger "remove" jQuery calls the native `.remove()` method of the node which then removes the element.

The relevant part in [jQuery/event.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L386):

```
if ( ontype && jQuery.isFunction( elem[ type ] ) && !jQuery.isWindow( elem ) ) {
    // ...
    elem[ type ]();    // elem["remove"]();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

.trigger() is simply a way of triggering an action upon load, whereas .remove() is a method that can be placed within a triggered action (whether automatic or manual). If you are using .trigger('remove') then there seems no point in having that element in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

[The trigger function](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

I included the trigger function for your reference, but yes that is the expected behavior. 
Trigger allows you to manually (or not) execute an event such as remove in your case. This would normally be for support on a "on()" function. For example

`( "#logo-events" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#logo-events" ).trigger( "click" );`

This block manually triggers a click function, but what it doesn't say is that if you just run a trigger on an element with no event, yet a function it just executes the function.

for example:

```
$("logo-events").trigger("remove");
```

The following will just run.

Hope that helps.